# How to export iGraph plots to browser

Tags: r, rstudio, igraph

I am trying to export an interactive graph to the browser (rather than the Rstudio viewer). I know this is possible (by default) with standard R.

How would I do this with Rstudio? This works in R:

```
library(networkD3)
simpleNetwork(MY_FILE) #displays in browser
```

Comment: What code are you running? Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). How is Rstudio specifically causing a problem?

Comment: Rstudio is not causing a problem, I just dont know how to do this is Rstudio whereas it happens by default in R.

Comment: There is a button in RStudio viewer (top right, "show in new window"). Or type `g1 <- simpleNetwork(NetworkData); htmltools::html_print(g1, viewer = utils::browseURL)`

Comment: @bergant, That fixed my problem. If you will propose it as a solution I will be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1):

There is a button in RStudio viewer (top right, "show in new window").

Or use `htmltools::html_print`  and specify viewer function:

```
g1 <- simpleNetwork(NetworkData)
htmltools::html_print(g1, viewer = utils::browseURL)
```